# How do I save the results into the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, for-loop

I am currently having trouble out a method to save the results in the file I provided through my sys.argv[1]. I am providing a csv to the python script.

My csv has data in the format like this

```
3/4/20

3/5/20

3/6/20
```

I have tried using append() but I am receiving errors, I also attempted using write()

```
import sys

file = open(str(sys.argv[1])) #enter csv path name, make sure the file only contains the dates
for i in file:
    addedstring = (i.rstrip() +',09,00, 17')
    finalstring = addedstring.replace("20,", "2020,")

file.append(i)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: need more clarity on what you are trying to achieve. are you trying to read the csv or trying to write data into csv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to put the modified strings into a list, then close the file, re-open for writing, and write the list of modified strings:

```
finalstring = []
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file:
    for i in file:
        addedstring = (i.rstrip() +',09,00, 17')
        finalstring.append(addedstring.replace('20,', '2020,'))
with open(sys.argv[1], "w") as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(finalstring))
```